# Pyspark Crosstab Pivot Challenge / Problem

Tags: pyspark, pivot, crosstab

I unfortunately could not find a solution for my exact problem. It is related to pivot and crosstab but I could not solve it with these functions.
I have the feeling I am missing an in-between-table, but I somehow cannot come up with a solution.

Problem description:

A table with customers indicating from which category they have bought a product. If the customer bought a product from the category, the category ID will be shown next to his name.

There are 4 categories 1 - 4 and 3 customers A, B, C

```
+--------+----------+
|customer| category |
+--------+----------+
|       A|         1|
|       A|         2|
|       A|         3|
|       B|         1|
|       B|         4|
|       C|         1|
|       C|         3|
|       C|         4|
+--------+----------+
```

The table is DISTINCT meaning there is only one combination of custmer and category

What I want is a crosstab by category where I can easily read e.g. how many of those who bought from category 1 also bought from category 4?

Desired results table:

```
+--------+---+---+---+---+
|        | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+--------+---+---+---+---+
|       1|  3|  1|  2|  2|
|       2|  1|  1|  1|  0|
|       3|  2|  1|  2|  1|
|       4|  2|  0|  1|  1|
+--------+---+---+---+---+
```

Reading examples:
row1 column1 : total number of customers who bought product 1 (A, B, C)
row1 column2 : number of customers who bought product 1 and 2 (A)
row1 column3 : number of customers who bought product 1 and 3 (A, C)
etc.
As you can see the table is mirrored by its diagonal.

Any suggestions how to created the desired table?

Additional challenge:
How to get the results as %?
For the first row the results wold be then: | 100% | 33% | 66% | 66% |

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the input data with itself using `customer` as join criterium. This returns all combinations of categories that exist for a given customer. After that you can use [crosstab](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crosstab) to get the result.

```python
df2 = df.withColumnRenamed("category", "cat1").join(df.withColumnRenamed("category", "cat2"), "customer") \
  .crosstab("cat1", "cat2") \
  .orderBy("cat1_cat2") 
df2.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+---+---+---+---+
|cat1_cat2|  1|  2|  3|  4|
+---------+---+---+---+---+
|        1|  3|  1|  2|  2|
|        2|  1|  1|  1|  0|
|        3|  2|  1|  2|  1|
|        4|  2|  0|  1|  2|
+---------+---+---+---+---+
```

To get the relative frequency you can sum over each row and then divide each element by this sum.

```python
df2.withColumn("sum", sum(df2[col] for col in df2.columns if col != "cat1_cat2")) \
  .select("cat1_cat2", *(F.round(df2[col]/F.col("sum"),2).alias(col) for col in df2.columns if col != "cat1_cat2")) \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+----+----+----+----+
|cat1_cat2|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+---------+----+----+----+----+
|        1|0.38|0.13|0.25|0.25|
|        2|0.33|0.33|0.33| 0.0|
|        3|0.33|0.17|0.33|0.17|
|        4| 0.4| 0.0| 0.2| 0.4|
+---------+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks for your help. The first solution works perfectly!
The second needed to be modified as the basis (100%) is always the diagonal (1-1; 2-2 etc).
So I ammended your solution by the following:
Count distinct customers per category and join it to the crosstable and use it instead of the sum of the row:
`df2 = df2.join(df_max.withColumnRenamed('category', 'cat1_cat2'), 'cat1_cat2', 'inner')
cz3 = df2.select("cat1_cat2", *(F.round(df2[col]/F.col("total"),2).alias(col) for col in df2.columns if col != "cat1_cat2"))`

Comment: Oh i forgot to show where "df_max" comes from:
`df_max = df.groupBy('category').agg(F.countDistinct('customer').alias('total'))`